# How can I use ktfmtFormat to format project's existing kotlin files?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, formatting, ktfmt

My project files have different formatting of kotlin and I want to use ktfmtFormat gradle plugin on Android Studio on windows. What is a command-line script to apply the formatting to all kotlin files?

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct task according to the docs, so from the command line it would be e.g. `.\gradlew.bat :ktfmtFormat`. There is also a JVM-based [standalone CLI](https://github.com/facebook/ktfmt#from-the-command-line).